# Angular – TailwindCSS not working with isolated components in <ng-content>

Tags: html, angular, tailwind-css

To keep it simple lets say i have this scenario:

```html
<main>
  <!-- Left Column -->
  <section>
    X
  </section>

  <!-- Right Column -->
  <section>
    Y
  </section>
</main>
```

Now lets imagine i want to add some TailwindCSS to main and section tags:

```html
<main
    class="
        p-2
        gap-2
        flex
        flex-col
        items-center
        flex-auto
        min-w-0
        justify-center
        md:flex-row
    ">

  <!-- Left Column -->
  <section
        class="
            w-full
            h-full
            p-5
            bg-card
            shadow
            items-center
            justify-center
            rounded-t-xl
            rounded-b-none
            flex
            md:w-1/2
            md:h-full
            md:rounded-l-xl
            md:rounded-r-none
            sm:bg-card
        ">
    X
  </section>

  <!-- Right Column -->
  <section
        class="
            w-full
            h-full
            p-5
            shadow
            items-center
            justify-center
            rounded-b-xl
            rounded-t-none
            relative
            overflow-hidden
            bg-gray-800
            dark:border-l
            flex
            md:w-1/2
            md:h-full
            md:rounded-r-xl
            md:rounded-l-none
            sm:bg-card
            sm:p-10
        ">
    Y
  </section>
</main>
```

The problem is, i want multiple Auth pages to use this exact layout (login, register, forgot password, reset password, confirm email, etc), and only change content within those left and right column sections.

This structure and styles defined as they are, work completely fine. My tailwindcss has been configured correctly in the angular project.

Instead of defining these styles and structure every time in every Auth page, it is reasonable to isolate them in separate components and reuse them, right?

That's what I did:

`auth-layout-wrapper.component.html`:

```html
<main
    class="
        p-2
        gap-2
        flex
        flex-col
        items-center
        flex-auto
        min-w-0
        justify-center
        md:flex-row
    "
>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</main>
```

`auth-left-column-wrapper.component.html`:

```html
<section
    class="
        w-full
        h-full
        p-5
        bg-card
        shadow
        items-center
        justify-center
        rounded-t-xl
        rounded-b-none
        flex
        md:w-1/2
        md:h-full
        md:rounded-l-xl
        md:rounded-r-none
        sm:bg-card
    "
>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</section>
```

`auth-right-column-wrapper.component.html`:

```html
<section
    class="
        w-full
        h-full
        p-5
        shadow
        items-center
        justify-center
        rounded-b-xl
        rounded-t-none
        relative
        overflow-hidden
        bg-gray-800
        dark:border-l
        flex
        md:w-1/2
        md:h-full
        md:rounded-r-xl
        md:rounded-l-none
        sm:bg-card
        sm:p-10
    "
>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</section>
```

And then in the Auth pages when i want to reuse these components i just do:

```html
<app-auth-layout-wrapper>
  <!-- Left Column -->
  <app-auth-left-column-wrapper>
    X
  </app-auth-left-column-wrapper>
  
  <!-- Right Column -->
  <app-auth-right-column-wrapper>
    Y
  </app-auth-right-column-wrapper>
</app-auth-layout-wrapper>
```

However, Now the styling is completely broken. Some styles work, some don't. Even though the structure is exactly the same, the styles are exactly the same, it's not getting styles as it was prior to isolating to components like this.

Why?

How can i isolate common layout components and still reuse the exact same styling as if it was hardcoded in every single page that needs to use that particular styling and layout structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entire point of creating an Angular component is to avoid repeating Tailwind CSS classes that seems like you are misusing both Angular and Tailwind.

If you need to apply the same 19 classes to multiple elements to make it look correct... something is wrong. Use [the Tailwind @apply feature](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) so you don't have to be so verbose with CSS classes.

```css
.left-column {
  @apply p-2 gap-2 flex flex-col items-center flex-auto min-w-0 justify-center md:flex-row;
}

.right-column {
  @apply w-full h-full p-5 shadow items-center justify-center rounded-b-xl rounded-t-none relative overflow-hidden bg-gray-800 dark:border-l flex md:w-1/2 md:h-full md:rounded-r-xl md:rounded-l-none sm:bg-card sm:p-10;
}
```

If that can simplify your styling down to one class, now you hopefully don't need to create angular components at all, and all your repeated styles are managed in a single place.  Now you can just do this:

```html
<main>
  <!-- Left Column -->
  <section class="left-column">
    X
  </section>

  <!-- Right Column -->
  <section class="right-column">
    Y
  </section>
</main>
```

Generally my rule of thumb is to only create an angular component when it actually performs a function and has logic in it.  If you are creating an Angular component as a way to write less HTML/CSS, that is misusing the framework IMO. If you go to write a unit test for the component and there is nothing to test... then it should not be a component.

Comment: But that defeats the whole purpose of creating separate column components. this way i would have to add those exact same tailwind classes to 10+ pages that use this same layout. Why not define them once and then wrap around the content with it? Also I tried your solution but the styles are still broken. Some styles are applied while others are off

Comment: You're right. Please see my updated answer

Comment: I see. So if the approach i'm doing is wrong, what would be the right approach so i don't reuse the same tailwind classes and html structure in 10+ pages? In case you don't recommend your new solution, what would you recommend?

Comment: Well the solution I am providing in my answer is the one I am recommending. That's why I provided it as an answer.  That will use a feature of Tailwind that is built exactly for this, and it doesn't overly complicate Angular by building components simply to avoid copy/pasting HTML.

Comment: A bit weird solution in my opinion (using pre-built tailwind css in a custom css file), but it does work. I'll mark your solution as the answer. Thank you

Comment: Did you see the link?  That's exactly how Tailwind is means to be used. It's exactly for this purpose.  Tailwind lets you get stuff done quickly but it also becomes a mess of class names in your HTML. They allow you to save "common combination" of class names like this as a custom class.  Now you can just add `class="foo"` in multiple places _(instead of 19 class names)_, know what it means, and have a central area to update it in if it needs to change. See here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply